# Can you create a custom GTK Assistant with your own buttons?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtkassistant

I want to create a custom GTK Assistant with my own buttons to control moving forward and back pages. I also don't want to end the program so the pages will be constantly looped through.

I haven't been able to find anything on line about this, any help would be appreciated.

Or if there another good way to cycle through different pages/windows with buttons then that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you add your own buttons to a GtkAssistant?

Comment: Make the GtkAssistant jump from the last page to first one to create an endless loop.

Comment: I want to put the buttons in the place I want them and I don't want to have the bar at the top with the "x" and I don't want the cancel button also. When i put the application into full screen it gets rid of it (which is what I want), I just then need to have my own custom buttons controlling moving forward and back between the pages

Answer (score 1):

At that rate, you might be better off with a [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html).

Then set your window to [popup](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow-struct) or [undecorated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated).

Or for a harder way, you could subclass the whole GtkAssistant and create your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `GtkAssistantPageType` to `GTK_ASSISTANT_PAGE_CUSTOM` and create page with your own buttons, but you should manage button's signal.

The other solution is the `gtk_assistant_add_action_widget` function.